# Import list of IP addresses, resolve their hostnames, export IP and hostname to spreadsheet

Tags: powershell

Complete powershell noob here. I am attempting to do the following:

1. Import a list of IP addresses from a text file.
2. Obtain the hostname of each IP address. If unable to, provide the failure reason.
3. Export both IP address and hostname (or error) line by line in a CSV.

I was attempting to use the following script however I do not know what IP address is which since there are some errors:

```
get-content .\dnsip.txt | ForEach-Object {([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname
```

Can someone help me write a script that would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Get-Content .\dnsip.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = "" | Select-Object IPAddress,Hostname
    try { 
        $obj.Hostname = ([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname
    } catch { 
        $obj.Hostname = 'Unknown Host'
    } 
    $obj.IPAddress = $_
    $obj
} | Export-Csv -Path Output.csv -NoType
```

**Explanation:**

During each iteration, a new object `$obj` is created with two properties, `IPAddress` and `Hostname`, set as empty strings. A `try {}` block is used to attempt to retrieve the `Hostname` value using your method. If it succeeds, `Hostname` will be assigned the value returned by the command. If that throws an exception, it will be caught by the `catch {}` block. In side `catch {}`, the `Hostname` property is given a value of `Unknown Host`. Then `IPAddress` is assigned the current item processed (`$_`) from your `Get-Content`.

All custom objects are exported to `Output.csv` via `Export-Csv`. The `-NoType` switch prevents data type information from being printed at the top of the CSV file.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted and in an easy to understand fashion. Thank you so much! I'm going to try to use this to learn going forward how I can accomplish different things... slowly but surely I hope to someday understand!